# What is the name of this data structure?

Tags: data-structures, theory

I am trying to solve a problem efficiently.

The problem is to recurse over a set $\{0,1,\dots,n-1\}$ (as array) in ascending or descending order, while removing or re-adding items in $O(1)$ time.

A sample algorithm is shown below (pseudo-code):

```
function countswaps(n, x, y, unvisited)
{
    c = 0;
    remove(x, y from unvisited);
    for (j=n-1; j>y; j--)
    {
        if (not (j in unvisited)) continue;
        remove(j from unvisited);
        for (k=j-1; k>=0; k--)
        {
            if (not(k in unvisited)) continue;
            remove(k from unvisited);
            c += countswaps(n, k, j, unvisited);
            add(k to unvisited);
        }
        add(j to unvisited);
    }
    add(x,y to unvisited);
    return c;
}
```

Effectively I need to traverse the list, but at each time leave out those items (in ascending or descending order) that are already visited in previous recursion (it is a method to count all possible swaps for some permutations, ie involutions).

Originaly I implemented the `unvisited` structure simply by table of flags where each value was flagged as visited or not. However this structure does not reduce the amount of iterations over the remaining values, one still has to loop through these values and simply discard them, but checking if visited flag is set, is an $O(1)$ operation, so the algorithm iterates over whole list every time a swap combination is to be found.

I thought of using an alternative data structure which is a combination of an array and a doubly-linked list with extra pointers to first and last valid items.

```
unvisited = new Array(n);
for (i=0; i<n; i++)
{
    unvisited[i] = {val:i, prev:null, next:null};
    if (0 < i)
    {
        unvisited[i-1].next = unvisited[i];
        unvisited[i].prev = unvisited[i-1];
    }
}
unvisited.start = unvisited[0];
unvisited.end = unvisited[n-1];
```

To remove an item from the unvisited data structure, I use something similar to Knuth's observation, I simply re-assign the item's prev and next pointers. I do inverse operation when re-adding it back.

```
function removeEl(unvisited, x)
{
    // remove x from unvisited
    if (unvisited.start === unvisited[x]) unvisited.start = unvisited[x].next;
    if (unvisited.end === unvisited[x]) unvisited.end = unvisited[x].prev;
    if (unvisited[x].prev)
        unvisited[x].prev.next = unvisited[x].next;
    if (unvisited[x].next)
        unvisited[x].next.prev = unvisited[x].prev;
}
function addEl(unvisited, x)
{
    // add x to unvisited
    if (unvisited.start === unvisited[x].next) unvisited.start = unvisited[x];
    if (unvisited.end === unvisited[x].prev) unvisited.end = unvisited[x];
    if (unvisited[x].prev)
        unvisited[x].prev.next = unvisited[x];
    if (unvisited[x].next)
        unvisited[x].next.prev = unvisited[x];
}
```

This works fine, and reduces the amount of iterations to linear time. However it's been a long time since my last Data Structures class, so how is this data structure (or something similar to it) called? If you can point a reference I would be extra grateful.

Thank you.

Comment: Most hand-crafted data structures dont really have a name. I didn't read the entire post, but why wouldn't you consider this as a modified doubly linked list?

Comment: It is a combination of a doubly-linked list and an array which allows $O(1)$ retrieval (unlike a list) and also $O(1)$ removal and re-addition, and efficient traversal of only valid items in each step. I though something that satisfies those conditions might have already  a name

Comment: I want to make it a distinct data structure in my code, so instead of coming up with a name I ask if there is already one. Right now I call this`ListSet` as it is a list inside something that resembles a set.